# What would be a good approach to construct docker containers for nginx, uwsgi, django

Tags: python, django, docker, nginx, web-applications

I have an approach that use a base OS image to construct nginx, uwsgi, django all inside a container for the purpose to fast deploy a website on a cloud service. And I also successfully building a reverse proxy to point to different django apps, but still inside one container. This approach has the drawback that, when I update one of the services or apps, I need to completely destroy the whole container and create a new container with all services. Therefore, I want to construct for nginx, uwsgi each with one container, for each django app a container. In short, I want to separate apps and services each with a container. Most of the tutorials online deploy such combinations inside one container.

So my question is what would be the best approach to do so? For services such as nginx, uwsgi, should I construct them without a base OS image but simply just the service image, or I should construct them each with a base OS image and then add the service on top? Also, for my Django apps, should I construct for each app with a base OS image or just start base with python image?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to deploy each service separately and NGINX server will listen on 80(http) or 443(https) port to act as a reverser poxy for all other containers.

You can use docker-compose to run all containers with a file, also you need to create docker network which helps you to achieve zero downtime for any service upgrade.

There are many more examples available on the internet.

have a look at blog:
https://devopsdevelopment.wordpress.com/2017/08/02/how-to-configure-docker-with-nginx-and-php-application/